# error regular comes Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, MyBase.Activated
    con.Close()

    con.Open()
    str = "select * from customer where CustomerID='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    If IsNumeric(ComboBox1.Text) Then
        cmd.CommandText = str = "select * from customer where CustomerID=@cid"
        cmd.Prepare()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cid", ComboBox1.Text)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Try
            If dr.Read() Then
                TextBox1.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
                TextBox2.Text = dr.GetValue(2)
                TextBox3.Text = dr.GetValue(3)
                TextBox4.Text = dr.GetValue(4)
                TextBox5.Text = dr.GetValue(5)
                dr.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("", ex.Message)
            dr.Close()
        Finally
            con.Close()

        End Try
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several issues.

1. You did not provide your complete `Combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method. At least the last line that ends the method is missing.
2. You are reusing a connection. It is better practice to create a new connection (and dispose it afterwards) each time you need it. (Connection pooling might already reuse connections in the background.)
3. You have an exception handling mechanism that doesn't cover all your logic that can throw exceptions.
4. You are using two approaches to pass the SQL command text to the command object. One approach should suffice.
5. You call the `Prepare` method *before* you add your parameters to the command object. Apart from the fact that calling `Prepare` probably is not explicitly needed, I guess it should be called *after* you have added your parameters to the command object.
6. You are using the `AddWithValue` method to add parameters to your command object. That is [evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, MyBase.Activated
  'Better to use explicit column names instead of * here, especially if you use `GetValue` with a numeric index when mapping the query results to your textboxes.
  Dim str As String = "select * from customer where CustomerID=@cid"

  Try
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("<connection string here>"), cmd As New OleDbCommand(str, con)
      con.Open()

      'Assuming here that CustomerID in the customer table is of type integer
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Integer.Parse(ComboBox1.Text)

      Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
          'Instead of using magical (ordinal) numbers, it would be better to use GetOrdinal as well: dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("fieldName"))
          TextBox1.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
          TextBox2.Text = dr.GetValue(2)
          TextBox3.Text = dr.GetValue(3)
          TextBox4.Text = dr.GetValue(4)
          TextBox5.Text = dr.GetValue(5)
        End If
        'Perhaps you also want to include an Else block (in which case the database query did not return any results) to clear the textboxes?
      End Using
    End Using
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("", ex.Message)
    'Closing any ADO.NET objects will be done automatically when they are disposed (when the Using block goes out of scope).
  End Try
End Sub
```

Obviously, I have not tested the code above, since I do not have a fitting test environment for it. Please let me know if this code causes any issues you cannot solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have two Sql statements in your code.

1:

> str = "select * from customer where CustomerID='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

2:

> cmd.CommandText = str = "select * from customer where CustomerID=@cid"

You should get rid of #1 - delete that line of code and change #2 to be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from customer where CustomerID=@cid"
```